# How to fix type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Flutter beginner here; I'm getting this error: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Function that fetch download url from firebase storage

```
_getImageUrl(var fileName) async {
  print(fileName);
  final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('categories/' + fileName);
  Uri downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  var url = downloadUrl.toString();
  return url;
}
```

where I called the function

```
child:  Image(
  image:  AdvancedNetworkImage(
    _getImageUrl(menuItem['image'].toString()),
    timeoutDuration: Duration(minutes: 1),
    useDiskCache: true,
    cacheRule: CacheRule(maxAge: const Duration(days: 7)),
  ),
  height: mediaQuery.size.width * 0.22,
  width: mediaQuery.size.width * 0.22,
),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 14):

You cannot use `async/await` when returning from a `build` method (or a `builder` closure). Any time you have async when building the widget tree, it's best to use a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
child: FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _getImageUrl(menuItem['image'].toString()),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Image(
        image: AdvancedNetworkImage(
          snapshot.data,
          timeoutDuration: Duration(minutes: 1),
          useDiskCache: true,
          cacheRule: CacheRule(maxAge: const Duration(days: 7)),
        ),
        height: mediaQuery.size.width * 0.22,
        width: mediaQuery.size.width * 0.22,
      );
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
),
```

Alternatively, you *could* use a `StatefulWidget` for this but it's much more boilerplate. There are more details and a live sample at https://flutterigniter.com/build-widget-with-async-method-call/ if you're interested.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly Flutter returns a `Future<type>` when the `asynchronous` functions is not completed, when it is completes it will return data of the type `type`. The mistake you are making is calling an `asynchronous` from a `synchronous` function. Although dart will execute the functions `asynchronously` (You can validate this by printing the url from the `asynchronous` function).
 But the place you are calling it from is not waiting for the `asynchronous` function to finish.

I hope it is clear now.
 For more clarity visit  [Asynchronous Programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score -6):

Your `_getImageUrl` shoul return a `Future<String>` .

Comment: now i am getting this error  'The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.'

Comment: use `await` before call this function