# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `initializeThemeData()` which returns `ThemeData` for the whole app.

```
# main.dart

Future<ThemeData> initializeThemeData() async {
  
  
  return ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(Client().getBackgroundColor()),
    );
}
```

This `ThemeData()` uses a background color of `Client().getBackgroundColor()`:

```
# get_client_settings.dart 

class Client {
  getBackgroundColor() async {
    var settings = await getSettings();
    var hexColor = settings["view_background_color"];
    return int.parse("0xFF" + hexColor.substring(1));
  }
}
```

`Client` class awaits another method called `getSettings` which returns a json:

```
# load_settings.dart 

getSettings() async {
  String jsonData =
      await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config/client_settings.json');
  Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
  return data;
}
```

`getSettings` loads the json from a json file which has the backgroundcolor value i want to use:

```
{
   "view_background_color" : "#f5f242" 
}
```

But when i run the app i get the error: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'`

## EDIT:

I know it has to do with the `Future` and i should use `FutureBuilder`
There is similar question in the link [How to fix type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150854/how-to-fix-type-futuredynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-flutter)

But if i have to use FutureBuilder, how can i then use it for my situation without placing everything in one file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150854/how-to-fix-type-futuredynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-flutter)

Comment: The answer also says that i have to use FutureBuilder, but i don't know how i can integrated in my app without placing everything in one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be a int instead of Future

```
scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(await Client().getBackgroundColor()),
```

Comment: @FDjawid you should also annotate the return types of your functions/methods. https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-annotate-return-types-on-function-declarations

Comment: That is a good tip thank i added `Future<int> getBackgroundColor()`

Comment: @FDjawid you can annotate `getSettings` as well `Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getSettings()`

Comment: yes you are right thanks i added that as well